# Unable to ChangeType from string to int?

Tags: c#, .net, casting, type-conversion

In the depths of our application there is an attempt to perform a conversion from a string to a nullable int with a `Convert.ChangeType(value, castType)`.  In this case the values are as follows:

```
value: "00010"
castType: Nullable<System.Int16>
```

The issue is that I am receiving the following error

```
Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'System.Nullable`1[[System.Int16}
```

I had (obviously incorrectly) believed this was similar to a cast or Convert.ToInt16() but I've verified it's not the same by testing the following two lines of code.

```
Int16 t = Convert.ToInt16("00010");
object w = Convert.ChangeType("00010", typeof(short?));
```

As you might suspect, the first succeeds whereas the second fails with the error message above.

Is it possible to use ChangeType in this fashion by making an adjustment or should I look at a refactor?

Comment: I ended up doing this based upon the information at the link: `Convert.ChangeType(value, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(castType) ?? castType);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to write something like this:

```
var value = "00010";
short? w = value == null ? null : (short?)Convert.ChangeType("00010", typeof(short));
```

`ChangeType` will not work with `Nullable<T>` - and if we have a value for `value`, we assume we have a value for the converted type

Comment: This is valuable but my values for the types are set at runtime with `typeof(T).GetProperty().PropertyType` so I'm not certain if I can do an explicit cast

Answer (score 3):

According to [`Convert.ChangeType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtb69x08(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The `ChangeType(Object, Type)` method can convert a nullable type to another type. However, **it cannot convert another type to a value of a nullable type**, even if `conversionType` is the underlying type of the `Nullable<T>`. **To perform the conversion, you can use a casting operator** (in C#) or a conversion function (in Visual Basic).

So, try:

```
var w = (short?)Convert.ChangeType("00010", typeof(short));
```

Comment: I completely missed the bolded section.  Thank you for pointing it out.